# PHP Imagick: copy a specific color from an image to a new image

Tags: php, image, colors, imagemagick, imagick

I have an image and I want to copy/extract a specific color (i.e., #00ffff) from the image, ideally specifying a fuzz factor, to a new image. I know about `transparentPaintImage()`, but it's unavailable in my environment (Ubuntu 10.04). Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy a colour" exactly? Can you show a before/after example?

Comment: I want to select a specific color and erase (turn into transparent) all other colors from the image.

Comment: That part alone should be relatively easy, if necessary by doing a pixel by pixel copy. The fuzz factor is what could make this complicated

Comment: Related: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/ (you might find what you need there)

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to compare pixel-by-pixel if that means a big performance hit -- I will need to keep performance in mind (this will have to be done on the fly).

Comment: I ended up circumventing my problem: instead of installing imagick with apt-get (which does not include transparentPaintImage() in Ubuntu 10.04), I installed it with pecl, which does include a current enough version that has transparentPaintImage().

Answer (score 1):

Well I just used this answer for another related question, you can isolate a specific colour, with a fuzz factor and save that to another channel.  On the command line you do it like so:

```
convert original.png -matte ( +clone -fuzz 5% -transparent #00ffff ) -compose DstOut -composite yellow-channel.png
```

Remembering that the brackets need escaping in bash, `\( \)`.

How this could be converted in to a sequence of IMagick commands, I'm not totally sure as I never use it.  I know you need to take the original image, make a clone, perform the transparency operation with fuzz and then use `compositeImage()` with the `DstOut` operator.  I dare say that would rely on the `paintTransparentImage()` function again though.  Indeed the command-line version will no doubt need that feature compiled in to the ImageMagick version in use.